# Unable to debug with F5 from visual studio 2013, modules window is empty

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to debug a program using *start external program* in Visual Studio 2013. All project files are .NET 3.5. As a sidenote: I have debugged like this since i updated to VS2013 (about two weeks), but today it suddently stopped working.

When I run the program it starts, but the *Debug->Windows->Modules* window is empty.

When I start the program and attach Visual Studio to process with **Managed (v3.5, v3.0, v2.0) code** everything loads smoothly and I am able to debug.
But when I choose **Managed (v4.5, v4.0) code** I get the same blank modules window as above and no active breakpoints.

Could it be that *start external program* uses the **Managed (v4.5, v4.0) code** instead of **Managed (v3.5, v3.0, v2.0) code**?
And is there any way to control which debugger Visual Studio uses when using *start external program*?

I have double checked that all project that builds with the debug-configuration is set to .NET 3.5 since my first thought was that one of the projects might build in a higher version. One project is .NET4.0 but is not set to build in my configuration.

Comment: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/768651/visual-studio-does-not-attaches-debugger

Comment: Solution #1 in the link you provided is the one I am using now. But Solution #2 is unfortunately not available since I dont have the source project for the .exe file.

Comment: You do not need source code.  You are not following the instructions.  You really *can* select an EXE file when you use File + Open Project.  The only thing you can do wrong is not trying it.

Comment: Your solution worked! Thank you very much. I would prefer not to include the exe file (Especially since it has worked just fine for the last two weeks) in all our products (100+ solutions) but if this is the only way it is better than not being able to debug earlier versions of our software at all. Post this as answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some research I ended up adding a .config-file for each version of the executable. The config-file must be named **ExecutableNameHere.exe.config**.

Here is the config I used for setting the active debugger to .NET 3.5:

```
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Just save the file in the same directory as the executable and the next time you debug it will use this .NET version.

For other .NET versions, replace version with the following:

- .NET Framework 1.0: "v1.0.3705"
- .NET Framework 1.1: "v1.1.4322"
- .NET Framework 2.0, 3.0, and 3.5: "v2.0.50727"
- .NET Framework 4 and 4.5 (including point releases such as 4.5.1): "v4.0"

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152935(v=vs.110).aspx