# Modules do not load while debugging external program

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2013

I've created a library for 3.5 framework version and set *Start action* on the *Debug* tab of the properties to *start external program* key with AutoCAD executable (acad.exe) as value. If I start debugging by pressing F5, project will be compiled and external program will run, but there is no modules will loaded and the program can not stop on break points. But if I start AutoCAD separately and then attach to it, all modules are loaded(but if program runes to the breakpoint, this leads to freezing of the acad.exe and not fires the breakpoint).

What must I do to fix this?

I also can not change *Enable native code debugging* option on *Debug* tab of the project neither *Use managed compatibility mode* in Debug options of the IDE due to the AutoCAD limitations(bug which crashes the app).

I tried to solve this by adding **.config** file, like [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22836618/unable-to-debug-with-f5-from-visual-studio-2013-modules-window-is-empty?rq=1), but it does not help, because, as I think, I start debugging with external program.

Comment: If [this tutorial](http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/index?siteID=123112&id=18172834) doesn't help (note the altered NETLOAD command) then use the vendor's support forum to find help.  Or pick up the phone, 6 months is a long time to get stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved by dettaching from acad.exe and attaching again with setting correct debug code type cases(Native and Managed code).